# Query have lots of result rows but when i loop through those rows, i only get two

Tags: php, mysql

My sites feed rss is being generated via php.

The query i use to retrieve the posts from mysql is:

```
$query = "select * from articles where status = 0 
          order by date desc LIMIT 0, 20";
```

then i do this loop to generate the XML feed:

```
$results = mysql_query($query,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($results);

for ($i=0; $i < $num_results; $i++) 
{ 
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results); 
  $date = strtotime($row['date']);
  $artdate = date('D, d M Y H:i:s O', $date);

  $rssfeed .= '<item>';
  $rssfeed .= '<title>' . utf8_decode($row['title']) . '</title>';
  $rssfeed .= '<link>'. $siteurl.'/article.php?id='.$row['id'] . '</link>';
  $rssfeed .= '<description>' . utf8_decode($row['resource']) . '</description>';
  $rssfeed .= '<guid>'. $siteurl.'/article.php?id='.$row['id'] . '</guid>';
  $rssfeed .= '<pubDate>' . $artdate . '</pubDate>';
  $rssfeed .= '</item>';
}
```

But the final xml generated have only the latest two posts.

That is limited to 20 on query, thought.

Funny thing is if i set LIMIT 0, 1 the final feed only have 1 post as it suposed to be.
But if i raise it to 20 it only have 2 posts, and i have more than two posts on that query.

Whats going on pls?

the full php code:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");

$cat = $_GET['cat'];

include ('config.php');

    $sitequery = 'select * from settings;';
    $siteresult = mysql_query($sitequery,$connection) or die(mysql_error());

    //Create site settings variables        
    $siteinfo = mysql_fetch_array($siteresult);
    $sitetitle = $siteinfo['title'];
    $siteurl = $siteinfo['url'];
    $logo = $siteinfo['logourl'];
    $statcode = $siteinfo['statcode'];

    if($cat) {
     $query = "select * from categories where id = ".$cat;
     $results = mysql_query($query,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
     $info = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
     $cattitle = htmlspecialchars($info['name']);

     $rssfeed = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
     $rssfeed .= '<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">';
     $rssfeed .= '<channel>';
     $rssfeed .= '<title>'.utf8_decode($cattitle).' - '.$sitetitle.'</title>';
     $rssfeed .= '<link>'.$siteurl.'</link>';
     $rssfeed .= '<description>'.$sitetitle.' RSS FEED</description>';
     $rssfeed .= '<language>pt-br</language>';
     $rssfeed .= '<copyright></copyright>';

    } else {
     $rssfeed = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
     $rssfeed .= '<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">';
     $rssfeed .= '<channel>';
     $rssfeed .= '<title>'.$sitetitle.'</title>';
     $rssfeed .= '<link>'.$siteurl.'</link>';
     $rssfeed .= '<description>'.$sitetitle.' RSS FEED</description>';
     $rssfeed .= '<language>pt-br</language>';
     $rssfeed .= '<copyright></copyright>';
    }

    if (!$cat){
     $query = "select * from articles where status = 0 
                 order by date desc LIMIT 0, 20";
    } else {
     $query = "select * from articles where status = 0 
              and categoryid = ".$cat." OR parentid =  ".$cat." 
              order by date desc LIMIT 0, 20";
    }

    $results = mysql_query($query,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $num_results = mysql_num_rows($results);

/*  for ($i=0; $i < $num_results; $i++) { 
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results); */

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) 
 {

  $date = strtotime($row['date']);
  $artdate = date('D, d M Y H:i:s O', $date);

  $rssfeed .= '<item>';
  $rssfeed .= '<title>' . utf8_decode($row['title']) . '</title>';
  $rssfeed .= '<link>'. $siteurl.'/article.php?id='.$row['id'] . '</link>';
  /*
     $rssfeed .= '<description>' . htmlspecialchars($row['body']) . 
                 '</description>'; */
  $rssfeed .= '<description>' . utf8_decode($row['resource']) . '</description>';
  $rssfeed .= '<guid>'. $siteurl.'/article.php?id='.$row['id'] . '</guid>';
  $rssfeed .= '<pubDate>' . $artdate . '</pubDate>';
  $rssfeed .= '</item>';
 }

  $rssfeed .= '</channel>';
  $rssfeed .= '</rss>';

  echo $rssfeed;
?>
```

Comment: Use of the mysql extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/book.mysqli) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/pdo_mysql) extension should be used.

Comment: did you run that query in mysql and verified that if 20 results are returned or only 2?

Comment: yes it is returning 20 results on mysql console

Comment: can you post your code that uses `$rssfeed`after this `for loop`

Comment: posted the full code, check again.

Comment: This is not related to your question but your second query should be `status = 0 and (categoryid = @var or parentid = @var)`

Comment: One of my posts had some special chars like &aacute; on database, instead of the utf8 version of this char. So the feed was not parsing as valid, that was my problem. converting those chars to utf8 encode solved the issue. Tahanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

its because the

```
for ($i=0; $i < $num_results; $i++) { 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
```

here the `$row` is assigned only one result so use like below

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
     $date = strtotime($row['date']);
     $artdate = date('D, d M Y H:i:s O', $date);

    $rssfeed .= '<item>';
    $rssfeed .= '<title>' . utf8_decode($row['title']) . '</title>';
    $rssfeed .= '<link>'. $siteurl.'/article.php?id='.$row['id'] . '</link>';
    $rssfeed .= '<description>' . utf8_decode($row['resource']) . '</description>';
    $rssfeed .= '<guid>'. $siteurl.'/article.php?id='.$row['id'] . '</guid>';
    $rssfeed .= '<pubDate>' . $artdate . '</pubDate>';
    $rssfeed .= '</item>';

  }
```

also use of the `mysql_*` function is deprecated use the `PDO` or `MYSQLi` instead

[Here is good pdo tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: tried, it still showing only 2 posts using while... I really cant undertand why thats happening.

Comment: @LucasMatos it mean you have only 2 post according your sql query